# R. mutate new variable based on conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a data frame (zz) with three variables (v1, v2 and v3). I want to mutate a new variable v4 based on some conditions.

1. if v3 <= 1 then v4=(v1+v2)/2....the mean.
2. if v3 >  1 then v4 = V1 or V2 whichever is greater.
3. if either of v1 or v2 is NA then v4 is the value of the non-NA variable.
4. if both v1 and v2 are NA then v4 is also NA
   The script below generates sample data and my start to the solution

```
v1 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, NA )
v2 <- c(6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, NA, 4)
v3 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, NA, NA)
zz <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)

zz = mutate(zz, v4 = ifelse( v3<=1, (v1+v2)/2,
                     ifelse( ?????)
```

Any guidance would be helpful

Comment: Try `pmax`: `mutate(zz, v4 = ifelse( v3<=1, (v1+v2)/2, pmax(v1,v2, na.rm=TRUE))`.

Comment: @nicola: Wanted to post the exact same comment. Was just about 10 seconds later. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case_when` to specify conditions. Condition 3 and 4 can be combined using `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

zz %>%
  mutate(v4 = case_when(v3 <= 1 ~ (v1 + v2)/2, 
                        v3 > 1 ~ pmax(v1, v2), 
                        TRUE ~ coalesce(v1, v2)))
#   v1 v2 v3  v4
#1   4  6  2 6.0
#2   4  2  2 4.0
#3   4  3  1 3.5
#4   4  3  1 3.5
#5   3  4  1 3.5
#6   5  4  2 5.0
#7   6  5  1 5.5
#8   7  7  0 7.0
#9   2 NA NA 2.0
#10 NA  4 NA 4.0
```

Comment: Works a treat.. never seen that command before.. coalesce. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
mutate(zz,
  v4 = ifelse(v3 <= 1,
    rowMeans(cbind(v1, v2), na.rm = TRUE),
    pmax(v1, v2, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. That nearly works except it delivers an NA for v4 instead of either v1 or v2 value if there is one. Lines 9 and 10 in the sample data the v4 result should be 2 and 4

Comment: @rustymarmot You are welcome. You didn't mention in you post that what happens if `NA` is in `V3`. You actually just showed the actions if either `V1` or `V2` is not NA.